# Simulated annealing algorithm: linear or polynomial time?

Tags: python, time-complexity, shortest-path, simulated-annealing

Normally, simulated annealing is used to find the shortest path in TSP problem. But in my case, I want to use it to find shortest path, and multiple visits for each cities is allowed. The shortest path result does not need to be optimal, just semi-optimal is also fine.

Therefore, considering my case, can this algorithm find the shortest path in a linear or polynomial time?

Comment: SA is just a meta-heuristic. Your problem does not matter, at least for a general remark like: yes, it can be used. How it can be used, asked like that, is too broad here, as a lot of details are involved and local-neighborhood definitions come into play. (Remark: nobody is using SA for TSP-like stuff in the real world). Re-reading your title: complexity + SA is somewhat hard to answer without a very clear formal definition. TSP is NP-hard, so SA can't be linear or polynomial in terms of worst-case optimum for the general TSP (and convergence-analysis is another complex thing...).